# IPython parent '/' is not a writable location

Tags: python-3.x, atom-editor, hydrogen

I am following this guideline to troubleshoot my atom+hydrogen installation:
https://nteract.gitbooks.io/hydrogen/content/docs/Troubleshooting.html

Specifically, trying to run this part:

```
python3 -m pip install ipykernel
python3 -m ipykernel install --user
```

after running the `python3 -m ipykernel install --user` I get the following error:

```
/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/IPython/paths.py:66: UserWarning: IPython parent '/' is not a writable location, using a temp directory.
  warn("IPython parent '{0}' is not a writable location,"
Installed kernelspec python3 in /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
```

I am wondering what this error actually means and how I can get around it. I ran this code with `sudo` as well but it didn't help

Comment: Perhaps [HOME](https://superuser.com/q/271925) is not set correctly? This can occur through [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html) or sever misconfiguration.

Comment: I am running this on a Mac. Does your recommendations apply to Mac as well?